# error while creating new react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

when I create a new react native app I got an error Faild to install the app, Make sure you have the android development environment
I opened the android studio to solve this problem I got
`import com.Facebook.react.PackageList`  can't solve this
so what is the problem and how can I fix it

Comment: What was the exact error?

Comment: com.facebook.react.PackageList  is unfound,

Answer (score 0):

change the line below in android/app/build.gradle file from

```
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+" // From node_modules
```

to specific version of my react-native as in package.json

```
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.5" // From node_modules
```

[image]